# Problem connecting to webrtc server when vpn without internet access is enabled

Tags: android, webrtc, video-streaming, vpn

I am developing an application that should connect to a remote webrtc server and stream video to it.
The application works properly and connects to the server. However, if the device is connected via vpn to a network that does not have Internet access, then there are connection problems. Most importantly, these problems only exist on devices or emulators with Android 9 or older, while the connection works without problems on Android 10 or newer. The connection problem occurs at the stage of collecting ice candidates. Here is an example of collecting ice candidates on Android 9 emulator:

```
iceGatheringState changed to GATHERING
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:3362660723 1 udp 2121998079 192.168.232.2 55845 typ host generation 0 ufrag /U+s network-id 5 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:2263735683 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.232.2 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag /U+s network-id 6 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:1527769438 1 tcp 1518207487 fec0::15:b2ff:fe00:0 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag /U+s network-id 7 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:4207765013 1 tcp 1518149375 192.168.200.2 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag /U+s network-id 3 network-cost 900","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:156986715 1 tcp 1518076415 fec0::f026:d1ff:fe26:53d7 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag /U+s network-id 4 network-cost 900","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceConnectionState changed to FAILED
```

As a result, the connection is terminated with the error IceConnectionState.FAILED.

At the same time, the process of collecting ice candidates on the Android 10 emulator (with same VPN connection) is as follows:

```
iceGatheringState changed to GATHERING
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:841689039 1 udp 2121998079 10.0.2.16 46049 typ host generation 0 ufrag c4PG network-id 5 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:842163049 1 udp 1685790463 5.128.201.35 63668 typ srflx raddr 10.0.2.16 rport 46049 generation 0 ufrag c4PG network-id 5 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":"stun:108.177.14.127:19302"}
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:2091440959 1 tcp 1518280447 10.0.2.16 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag c4PG network-id 6 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:1527769438 1 tcp 1518207487 fec0::15:b2ff:fe00:0 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag c4PG network-id 7 network-cost 10","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:1847424209 1 tcp 1518149375 10.0.2.15 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag c4PG network-id 3 network-cost 900","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceCandidate={"adapterType":"UNKNOWN","sdp":"candidate:3215348137 1 tcp 1518076415 fec0::787f:cfff:feca:4766 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 ufrag c4PG network-id 4 network-cost 900","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"data","serverUrl":""}
iceGatheringState changed to COMPLETE
iceConnectionState changed to CONNECTED
```

As can be seen, on different versions of Android the webrtc library receives completely different ice candidates. Looks like on Android 9 ice candidates. Perhaps webrtc on Android 9 looks for ice candidates in a private VPN network, while on Android 10 ice candidates are collected from the internet and bypass the VPN network? In that case, how to change this behavior for Android 9 in my application?

To connect to the webrtc server from the client side I use the google-webrtc library for android. These Ice Servers are used for Peer Connection Configuration:

```
turn:numb.viagenie.ca
stun:stun.l.google.com:19302
stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302
stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302
stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302
stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302
```

Webrtc server is based on Janus.